# How do I set up libgdx for netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, libgdx

I googled it and it's hard to find a tutorial using layman's terms, a video, or picture. And a lot of the tutorials are used for eclipse.

Could someone explain to me how to use libgdx on netbeans?

Comment: Have you tried following [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle) and then [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-NetBeans)?  Btw did you [install the Gradle plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support)?  Detailed setup procedure is [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I got it to work. But now I'm wondering how to code a game, and make an app or maybe a desktop game. I know Java already, but the Java I learned in class weren't exactly teaching me how to create my own classes.

Comment: Great!  Now, how to code a game is an entirely different question, but not the type of questions SO is specialized in - have a look at [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  The best thing to do is to learn from examples and formulate *specific* questions and problems you encounter in new questions.  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XlNYPFc9K8&ab_channel=MarioZechner) on youtube on how to setup a libGDX project in netbeans (You can also checkout the [previous episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTC922ki2mc&ab_channel=MarioZechner) which shows how to setup environment for java). But you can also follow along with setting up the environment as described on libGDX's website.

The idea's simple, you [setup your java environment](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation/gettingstarted/Setting%20Up.html#setting-up-netbeans) with all the requirements needed, depending on what exactly you want to build for (maybe even buy a mac whilst you are at it). In this case, JDK 8+.

Afterwards you have to [import the project into netbeans](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation/gettingstarted/Importing%20into%20IDE.html#netbeans) like you would any other project.